# Power BI DAX, END OF MONTH DOESN'T WORK WITH DATE TABLE

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

When using endofmonth dax statement with my fact table it works:

```
EOM = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[sales]),
    ENDOFMONTH('Table'[date])
)
```

However when I use it with my date table it returns blanks does anyone know why?

dax command using my date table:

```
EOM_DTBLE = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[sales]),
    ENDOFMONTH('DATE'[Date])
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check what end of month returns first:

If we test it with a simple code:

```
Test = CALCULATE(ENDOFMONTH('Date'[Date]))
```

[image: FRST]

So basically, It returns the last date of each month. If you have no data in the end of the month specified, It returns empty.

If you have data (I have 679 on 31/01/2022) then, Code returns:

[image: FDF]

Comment: It must be the way the fact and dimension tables are related. I have tested the above you suggested  Calculate end of month without the sales values and with the sales table it gets the correct end of month date and for the date table it gets the end of month date that is the actual last day of the month so e.g. say the last sale of jan occurs on the 25/01/2022 when i use the end of month for the sales table it returns with the date 25/01/2022 but when I use the end of month with the date table it returns with 31/01/2022

Comment: So which one is your preference ?

Comment: to use the endofmonth with the date table but for the result to be correct such as the result I am getting when using the endofmonth with the sales table

Comment: Then use this measure: EOM_DTBLE_01 = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Table'[sales]),
    'Date'[Date]<= MAX('Date'[Date])
)

Comment: thanks for your help and also I have just understood what I was trying to do wrong as the end of month for the date table doesn't have a corresponding value in the sales table it doesn't work in power bi that is why you have applied a work around for it to work.

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, Exactly! If you think your problem is solved, Then that's the most important thing here. Stay safe!